# differences between locked administrator account and unlocked one

Tags: users

when I check my single user account through "system settings" it is said on the top of the window that my administrator account is locked and I have the choice to make it unlocked. what would be the utilities of locking it up?

Comment: If unlocked it will allow the user to edit admin details(options).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent other users from making changes to your account. In order to edit anything, you need to unlock access. It locks automatically when you exit/close the window.